# How to fix hard-disk error connected by usb?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, usb-drive, smartctl

My system is Linux 64bit, my hard-disk is a 1TB *WD* HD, connected to my computer by USB3.0. I found some files cannot be copied, they are video files, and it seems I can play the video. I ran `e2fsck -fy /dev/sdb1` and no errors found. Then I read [this](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html) article and tried the `smartctl` tool. But, I think it is because the HD is connected through USB, that the `smartctl` tools says the `selftest` function is not supported.

I used both drag-drop and `rsync` to try to copy the file, and both attempt results **read error**. I did not see more specific error message, or I do not know where to look at. :(

Now, I have no idea how to fix this disk error without format my disk, which I do not want.

Comment: Cannot be copied by open them in editors, that's interesting

Comment: it's video file. sorry I was not clear ;)

Comment: A video can be played partly even if some part is broken, depends on its encoding

Comment: We don't know if you've got a disk error yet.  Please post the error you get when you try and copy the files, including the command you use to copy them.

Comment: I checked my copy destination and my OS, and everything is fine. And each time I copy the file, I got a **read error**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `-d sat`, `-d usbcypress`, `-d usbjmicron`, `-d usbsunplus` to your `smartctl` command line, to use a transfer format that can pass through the USB-SATA bridge chip.

You can also try connecting it to a USB 2.0 hub / port, which may cause the bridge to behave differently in regards to ATA passthrough.

If none of those work, you can always just remove the hard drive from its external enclosure and connect it to your motherboard directly.